# parsing and rendering PDF's on canvas as image in flutter

Tags: pdf, dart, flutter

I want to render pdf as an image on canvas in custom painter for my viewer.
Can anyone suggest a library or package or a way to parse and render PDFs in DART, Flutter?

Answer (score 1):

There are none.

But recently Flutter added support for platform views. That means you can use Android and iOS PDF components and embed them in Flutter, [using Flutter's `PlatformView` feature](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-platformview-how-to-create-flutter-widgets-from-native-views-366e378115b6).

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it might work for you:

https://pub.dev/packages/native_pdf_renderer